# Add user to role when they sign up

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Is it possible to add users to role when they sign up? And add them as Basic user?

I have been trying for a while now but can not seem to figure it out.

For my signup script I use the following code:

```
func SignUp() {

    let user = PFUser()
    user.username = UsernameTextField.text
    user.password = PasswordTF.text
    user.email = EmailTF.text


    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {


            // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
            let alertcontroller = UIAlertController(title: "Russeradar", message: "Din bruker er nå opprettet! Du kan nå logge in" , preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alertcontroller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alertcontroller,animated: true, completion: nil)


        } else {
            // Examine the error object and inform the user.
            let alertcontroller = UIAlertController(title: "Russeradar", message: "Din bruker kunne ikke opprettes. Prøv på nytt senere!" , preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alertcontroller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alertcontroller,animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

If I need to provide more information, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do this in your "if error == nil" conditional, after the user has been signed up in the background

Below would create a role. roleName being "Basic User" in your case

```
var role = PFRole.roleWithName(roleName, acl:roleACL)
role.users.addObject(user) 
role.saveInBackground()
```

To set a role ACL (For e.g.) take a look at the api in the comments for more methods to use

```
var roleACL = PFACL.ACL()
roleACL.setPublicReadAccess(true)
```

Comment: Okei, thank you. I am very new to this. How do i define ACL? And don't i need to save user as username? Like if i would say that signup user got role basic user/user

Comment: Are you trying to break up your users into two categories, Administrators and Basic users?

Comment: For more specific methods take a look at that link, contains the API.

Comment: Did not figure it out.